# KeyWindow add subView, did not shows in the front

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow, keywindow

I use keyWindow to add a subView, it add success but did not shows in the front of the screen hierarchy.

The deep gray view is my added view:

[image]

My code is:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    LMLUpspringView *pop_v;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pop_v = [[LMLUpspringView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];

    UIWindow *keywindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];

    [keywindow addSubview:pop_v];

    //[keywindow bringSubviewToFront:pop_v];
    //[self.view addSubview:pop_v];

}
```

I have tried use `[keywindow bringSubviewToFront:pop_v]` to bring to front.But do not work.

And if I use `[self.view addSubview:pop_v]`, it shows in the front.

Answer (score 2):

You run into this issue, is caused by you do not know the difference between the `viewDidLoad`  method and the `viewDidAppear:` method.

> **viewWillAppear:**
>
> Called before the view is added to the windows’ view hierarchy
>
> **viewDidAppear:**
>
> Called after the view is added to the view hierarchy

The controller's view add to the window's view hierarchy is between`viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`, the `viewDidLoad` is in front of `viewWillAppear:`, so you can not do that. you should in `viewDidAppear:` add your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using appdelegate's Windows :

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.window addSubview:pop_v]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    LMLUpspringView *pop_v;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    pop_v = [[LMLUpspringView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

> UIWindow *keywindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

```
    [keywindow addSubview:pop_v];

    //[keywindow bringSubviewToFront:pop_v];
    //[self.view addSubview:pop_v];

}
```